How to Access Intermediate Steps of Langchain Agent React in Real-Time While Waiting for Final Response?
I am working with the AgentReact from the Langchain library and I need to access and display the intermediate steps (interactions) in real-time while waiting for the final response. Currently, my code only returns the interactions and the final result after the entire process is completed, which is not ideal for my application.
def question_answer(question: str, agents: AgentExecutor):
    
    list_logs_result = []
    answer = agents.invoke({'input': prompt_templates_100.format(question=question)}, )
    interactions = format_interactions(answer)

    
    for interaction in interactions:
        list_logs_result.append({"log": interaction["log"], "result": interaction["result"]})

    return answer["output"], list_logs_result


Do you want to perform some operation on intermediate steps as well? If you just want to analyze then langsmith provide detailed breakdown.

The return_intermediate_steps parameter for agents returns the only at the end of the Agent execution. You would need to implement a custom logic for this, preferably done using a generator of some sort since streaming does not seem suited for JSON content.

Have a look at async-stream-intermediate-steps
